# Opening a php server to connect a C application: Apache error 503

Tags: php, c, apache

I'm trying to establish a communication between a C program and PHP server.
PHP runs on apache server and acts as the server. C should be the client.

Posting here the code for the C client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

PHP server:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/* Wait for connections */
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 4444;
echo "Starting server at $address @ port $port";
if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
echo "socket_create() failure: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}
if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
echo "socket_bind() failure: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}
if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
echo "socket_listen() failure: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}
echo "Socket created, binded and listening to ...";
//clients array
$clients = array();
do {
$read = array();
$read[] = $sock;

$read = array_merge($read,$clients);

// Set up a blocking call to socket_select
if(socket_select($read,$write = NULL, $except = NULL, $tv_sec = 5) < 1)
{
// SocketServer::debug("Problem blocking socket_select?");
continue;
}

// Handle new Connections
if (in_array($sock, $read)) {  

if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
echo "socket_accept() failure: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
break;
}
$clients[] = $msgsock;
$key = array_keys($clients, $msgsock);

$msg = "\nHello \n" .
"client: {$key[0]}\n" .
"quit to quit\n";
socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

}

// Handle Input
foreach ($clients as $key => $client) { // for each client  
if (in_array($client, $read)) {
if (false === ($buf = socket_read($client, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
echo "socket_read() fail: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($client)) . "\n";
break 2;
}
if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
continue;
}
if ($buf == 'quit') {
unset($clients[$key]);
socket_close($client);
break;
}
if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
socket_close($client);
break 2;
}
$talkback = "Client {$key}: ha detto '$buf'.\n";
socket_write($client, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
echo "$buf\n";
}

}  
} while (true);
socket_close($sock);
?>
```

Few seconds after I load the PHP page I get an Apache 503 error, "Service Unavailable".
If I check for Apache server errors log I can see an "Apache 503 299" related to my php page.

Could someone please help me to get it to work ?

Comment: Your php page is socket server itself, not dependant on apache, you can run it on command line and send request from client directy

Comment: Thanks for your comment, sir. I should really use Apache cause the script is inside a web page. How could I work it around ?

Comment: Your php page look like a standalone server, are you not able to run from command line with php engine? e.g. php scriptname.php

Comment: Yes Pras, I can do it. But I need an output on the web page

Comment: If you want to use apache, you dont have to do socket operations in php page, reading from sockets,parsing request and creating response http headers will be taken care by apache, your php script should only concentrate on creating the content to be sent to client. Your clien will have to send get to post requst to apache requesting php page as resource

Comment: Now I'm starting to figure it out. Do you possibly have some resouces (examples, etc) where I can learn more about this ?